# How to make saved files end up nowhere?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I want to disallow a program from keeping local files, and I thought I would accomplish that by pointing a shortcut with its local folder's name to `/dev/null`, but I cannot seem to get it working.

If I try `ln .app /dev/null`, I get a message saying

> ln: ‘.app’: hard link not allowed for directory

And if I add symbolic, by doing `ln .app /dev/null -s`, then I get

> ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/dev/null’: File exists

So I don't really know how to accomplish this idea. What is the correct solution?

Comment: Your app is going to assume `.app` is a directory, but `/dev/null` is a file, so this isn't likely to work. See [How can I create a /dev/null-like “blackhole” directory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/how-can-i-create-a-dev-null-like-blackhole-directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using:

```
ln -s /dev/null .app
```

to create a symlink called `.app` pointing to `/dev/null`